# How do I add background images the <option> element of a <select> input?

Tags: css

I don't know if browsers support this or not. Works fine in a div, but that's not very semantic.

I've got a rough mock up here of what I'm looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgifford/xjkcgod8/5/

```css
/* All select elements on page */
select {
  position: relative;
}

/* Style by class. Effects the text of the contained options. */
.blueText {
  color: #0000FF;
}

/* Style by id. Effects position of the select drop down. */
#styledSelect {
  left: 100px;
}

#orange {
  color: orange;
}

#apple {
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-7/512/Apple-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 10px;
}

#cherry {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Styling</title>
  <link href="selectExample.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<select id="styledSelect" class="blueText">
  <option value="apple" id="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange" id="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="cherry" id="cherry">Cherry</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially I want to see a country name & flag associated for each item in the list. I just want to do a country dropdown, but HTML is failing me (or more likely my CSS chops).

Comment: For semantic purposes you could use `aria-*` for specifying roles for the screen readers etc. Native browser elements are very poor in their functionality so there is no hope for future support I guess.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of nuances in presentation layer dev. `<select>` is notorious for not being very flexible design wise, hence why most of us just create custom drop downs that we can make "prettier" and still retain full a11y, ARIA, etc standards with.

Answer (score 0):

you cant have background image for option tag. you can use some plugin like this if need to insert image in option.

You can use a custom jquery plugin like in this reference:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown